# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in nested for loop when index should not be reached

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package edu.bsu.cs222.twoWeekProject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class arraySorter {
public  arrayGroup sortByUsername(arrayGroup unsortedGroup) {
    ArrayList<String> array1 = unsortedGroup.array1;
    ArrayList<String> array2 = unsortedGroup.array2;
    ArrayList<String> noDuplicantsArray = removeDuplicantsFromArray(array1);
    String usernameTemp;
    String timestampTemp;
    int StartPosition;

    for(int i=0; i<noDuplicantsArray.size();i++) {
        StartPosition = getUsernameStartPosition(noDuplicantsArray.get(i), 
array1);
        for(int j=0; j<array1.size();j++) {
            if(noDuplicantsArray.get(i).equals(array1.get(j))) {
                usernameTemp = array1.get(j);
                timestampTemp = array2.get(j);
                array1.set(j, array1.get(StartPosition));
                array2.set(j, array2.get(StartPosition));
                array1.set(StartPosition, usernameTemp);
                array2.set(StartPosition, timestampTemp);
                StartPosition++;
            }
        }
    }
    arrayGroup finalArrays = new arrayGroup(array1, array2);
    return finalArrays;
}

public int getFrequency(String user, ArrayList<String> array) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<array.size(); i++){
        if(array.get(i).equals(user)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public int getUsernameStartPosition(String user, ArrayList<String> array) {
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<String> singleUserArray = removeDuplicantsFromArray(array);
    for(int i = 0; i<singleUserArray.size(); i++) {
        if(getFrequency(user, array) <= getFrequency(singleUserArray.get(i), 
array) && !singleUserArray.get(i).equals(user)) {
            count = count + getFrequency(singleUserArray.get(i), array);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public boolean isHigherInAlphabet(int startAt, String a, String b) {
        char aPart = a.charAt(startAt);
        char bPart = b.charAt(startAt);
        if (Character.getNumericValue(aPart) < 
Character.getNumericValue(bPart)) {
            return true;
        } else if(Character.getNumericValue(aPart) == 
Character.getNumericValue(bPart)) {
            return isHigherInAlphabet(startAt+1,a,b);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}

public ArrayList<String> removeDuplicantsFromArray(ArrayList<String> array) 
{
    ArrayList<String> returnArray = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++) {
        if(returnArray.contains(array.get(i))) {
        }else {
            returnArray.add(array.get(i));
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}


}
```

I am currently returning an IndexOutOfBoundsException. The program is claiming that the index (StartPosition) is growing too large for for it to be in the arraylist (like java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11) when the StartPosition should not be growing that large. The program is specifically failing on the line that reads: array1.set(j, array1.get(StartPosition));

edit:
The following is code from my testclass so that people can see what exactly the arrays look like... the only test that fails is testArraySorter()
    public class ArrayTests {
    package edu.bsu.cs222.twoWeekProject;

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class ArrayTests {

    private ArrayList<String> usersUnsorted = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> timestampsUnsorted = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> usersSorted = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> timestampsSorted = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> usersSingle = new ArrayList();

public void fillTestObjects() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        usersUnsorted.add("User1");
        timestampsUnsorted.add("User1 Time" + Integer.toString(i));
        usersUnsorted.add("User2");
        timestampsUnsorted.add("User2 Time" + Integer.toString(i));
    }
    usersUnsorted.add("User2");
    timestampsUnsorted.add("User2 Time Final");


    usersSorted.add("User2");
    usersSorted.add("User2");
    usersSorted.add("User2");
    usersSorted.add("User2");
    usersSorted.add("User2");
    usersSorted.add("User2");
    usersSorted.add("User1");
    usersSorted.add("User1");
    usersSorted.add("User1");
    usersSorted.add("User1");
    usersSorted.add("User1");
    timestampsSorted.add("User2 Time1");
    timestampsSorted.add("User2 Time2");
    timestampsSorted.add("User2 Time3");
    timestampsSorted.add("User2 Time4");
    timestampsSorted.add("User2 Time5");
    timestampsSorted.add("User2 Time Final");
    timestampsSorted.add("User1 Time1");
    timestampsSorted.add("User1 Time2");
    timestampsSorted.add("User1 Time3");
    timestampsSorted.add("User1 Time4");
    timestampsSorted.add("User1 Time5");

    usersSingle.add("User1");
    usersSingle.add("User2");
}

@Test
public void testFillObjects() {
    fillTestObjects();
    ArrayList<String> usersSingleCopy = new ArrayList();
    usersSingleCopy.add("User1");
    usersSingleCopy.add("User2");

    Assert.assertTrue(usersSingleCopy.equals(usersSingle));
}



@Test
public void testArrayGroupEqual() {
    fillTestObjects();
    ArrayList<String> usersSingleCopy = new ArrayList();
    usersSingleCopy.add("User1");
    usersSingleCopy.add("User2");
    arrayGroup unsortedGroup = new arrayGroup(usersSingle, timestampsUnsorted);
    arrayGroup unsortedGroup2 = new arrayGroup(usersSingleCopy, timestampsUnsorted);

    Assert.assertTrue(unsortedGroup.isEqualTo(unsortedGroup2));

}
@Test
public void testArrayGroupNotEqual() {
    fillTestObjects();
    arrayGroup unsortedGroup = new arrayGroup(usersUnsorted, timestampsUnsorted);
    arrayGroup sortedGroup = new arrayGroup(usersSorted, timestampsSorted);

    Assert.assertFalse(unsortedGroup.isEqualTo(sortedGroup));

}
@Test
public void testSimilarArrayGroupNotEqual() {
    fillTestObjects();
    arrayGroup unsortedGroup = new arrayGroup(usersUnsorted, timestampsUnsorted);
    arrayGroup sortedGroup = new arrayGroup(usersUnsorted, timestampsSorted);

    Assert.assertFalse(unsortedGroup.isEqualTo(sortedGroup));

}


@Test
public void testArraySorter() {
    fillTestObjects();
    arrayGroup unsortedGroup = new arrayGroup(usersUnsorted, timestampsUnsorted);
    arrayGroup sortedGroup = new arrayGroup(usersSorted, timestampsSorted);

    arraySorter arraysorter = new arraySorter();

    Assert.assertTrue(sortedGroup.isEqualTo(arraysorter.sortByUsername(unsortedGroup)));
}

@Test
public void testDuplicantRemoval() {
    fillTestObjects();
    arraySorter arraysorter = new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertTrue(usersSingle.equals(arraysorter.removeDuplicantsFromArray(usersUnsorted)));
}

@Test
public void testDuplicantRemovalSize() {
    fillTestObjects();
    arraySorter arraysorter = new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertEquals(arraysorter.removeDuplicantsFromArray(usersUnsorted).size(), 2);
}

@Test
public void testHigherInAlphabet() {
    fillTestObjects();

    arraySorter arraysorter=new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertTrue(arraysorter.isHigherInAlphabet(0, "Joa", "Job"));
}

@Test
public void testLowerInAlphabet() {
    fillTestObjects();

    arraySorter arraysorter=new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertFalse(arraysorter.isHigherInAlphabet(0, "Job", "Joa"));
}

@Test
public void testStartPositionUser1() {
    fillTestObjects();

    arraySorter arraysorter=new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertEquals(6, arraysorter.getUsernameStartPosition("User1", usersUnsorted));
}
@Test
public void testStartPositionUser2() {
    fillTestObjects();

    arraySorter arraysorter=new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertEquals(0, arraysorter.getUsernameStartPosition("User2", usersUnsorted));
}

@Test
public void testUser2Frequency() {
    fillTestObjects();

    arraySorter arraysorter=new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertEquals(6, arraysorter.getFrequency("User2", usersUnsorted));
}
@Test
public void testUser1Frequency() {
    fillTestObjects();

    arraySorter arraysorter=new arraySorter();
    Assert.assertEquals(5, arraysorter.getFrequency("User1", usersUnsorted));
}
```

}

Comment: This looks like an excellent time to use a debugger and see where it’s going wrong. Remember arrays start at index 0.

Comment: Are the sizes of array1 and array2 guaranteed to be equal? It seems that array2 size is never checked.

Comment: The size of array1 and array2 are gauranteed to be equal. The purpose of this is to organize array1 and array2 so that the same actions are taken to both of them. The array index does start at 0 and goes to the size of the array so there should be no problem with the number growing too large.

Comment: At a first glance doesn't seem to be wrong but it would be useful to see the array1 values giving you the issue. Eg: array1 = ["alice","bob","alice",etc...

Comment: I edited the original post to include my testclass

Comment: Also i figured out that the issue appears to be that my sorting function is moving objects once they have already been moved (like the 3rd object might be moved to the 6th place and then when it gets to the 6th place it tries to move it again so it increases the StartPosition by 1 twice). I am still not sure how to fix it though.